# Pass Criteria from Excel to VBA function call

Tags: excel, vba

### Background

I've a VBA function which takes a range of cells and does some operation on it and returns a value to be filled in cell.

```
Function ProcessCells(sheetName As String, ParamArray MyParams() As Variant) As String

.. 

End Function
```

This takes sheetName and MyParams as input. MyParams is a pair-wise list of argument containing columnIndex and filtertoApply on it.

Example Usage in my excel sheet:

```
=ProcessCells("my-sheet-1", "CarModel", "Honda", "City", "Vancouver")
```

This function call looks at data in sheet-1 filters rows where CarModel=Honda and City=Vancouver and then does some processing on the rows

### Problem

Instead of passing a value like "Honda" or "Vancouver" to perform filtering, I want to provide users to be able to pass a filter function from excel formula which I can run in my VBA function to filter out before processing.

Something like :

```
=ProcessCells("my-sheet-1", "CarModel", Val <> "Honda", "City", Value_in_List("Vancouver", "Vicotria"))
```

Similar to in built CountIf function which take Range and criteria :

```
=COUNTIF(Where do you want to look?, What do you want to look for?)
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

Answer (score 0):

Please, try calling it as:

```
=ProcessCells("my-sheet-1", "CarModel", "<>Honda", "City", {"Vancouver", "Vicotria"})
```

and use the second `ParamArray` element as filtering criteria for the first one column ("CarModel") and fourth like criteria array for filtering by the third ("City") column...